# Specific user can't run Spring Boot application on port 443, but root can do it

Tags: centos, java, port

I can't run a Spring Boot application on CentOS under a specific user on the port 443 (or 433 it doesn't matter).

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Root can do it. When I tried to run it on port 8761 (with the same specific user) it worked. Where should I apply this permission?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've found

```
The Well Known Ports (0-1023) – which are reserved for the operating system and core services. 
The Registered Ports (1024-49151) – which can be used by applications, specific services, and users. 
The Dynamic and/or Private Ports (49152-65535)
```

Comment: This does not answer the OPS question.